# Why is centripetal acceleration constant in this in this question?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, centripetal-force

This is a question I learnt in school.

> A cyclist is riding with a speed of 27kmh−1. As he approaches a circular turn on a road of radius 80 m, he applies brakes and reduces his speed at a constant rate of 0.5ms−2. What is the magnitude and direction of the net acceleration of the cyclist on the circular turn?

My teacher's solution is: 
[image]

$$a_c = v^2 / r = 7.5^2 / 80 = 0.7m/s^2$$

adding vectorially 
$$\therefore a_{net} = \sqrt{a_c^2 + a_t^2} = \sqrt{0.7^2 + 0.5^2} = 0.86m/s^2$$   
and then finding the angle.

I really don't get how this solution works. How can the centripetal force be constant since it's velocity is changing on the curve. Shouldn't it vary with time? 
Before seeing the solution I was doing something like this:
$$-dv/dt = 0.5$$
$$\int-dv = \int0.5dt$$
$$u - v = 0.5t$$
$$v = 7.5 - 0.5t$$
$$a_c^2 = v^2/r = (7.5 - 0.5t)^2 / 80 $$
Didn't know where to go from here.

I searched online to see other answers, they all did the same thing. 
https://www.toppr.com/ask/en-ae/question/a-cyclist-is-riding-with-a-speed-of-27-kmh/
https://doubtnut.com/question-answer-physics/a-cyclist-is-riding-with-a-speed-of-27-km-h-1-as-he-approaches-a-circular-turn-on-the-road-of-radius-17240018

Can anyone explain conceptually why these steps work?

Comment: You're mixing units of measurement: $\mathrm{km/h}$ and $\mathrm{m}$. First convert every thing to S.I. units: $\mathrm{m/s}$. As a result $a_c$ is wrong. But you're right that $a_c$ and $a_t$ cannot be constant.

Comment: I know, I was just too lazy to convert so I put the numbers with units

Comment: That CANNOT work.

Comment: Also, the actual calculation is irrelevant to my question. I was confused by the concepts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your teacher expects you to find the acceleration just at the instant the turn begins, when the speed is still 27 km/h.  You're right that as the cyclist slows down, the centripetal acceleration will decrease.

Comment: So is the question kind of framed in a bad way? I think it should be more like 'find the net acceleration at the start of the turn'

Comment: Yes, it's a poorly stated problem. Quite common in low quality textbooks.

Comment: @HaydenSoares It's a kind of silly example from a bicycling point of view, too. On a uniform surface, if the tires grip at the start of a circular turn, they'll grip through the whole turn, so there's no need to brake. Hitting the brakes right when you start turning actually makes you *more* likely to slip, since the magnitude of the acceleration is higher than an un-braked turn. The question states that the cyclist brakes when *approaching* the turn, which would be appropriate, but they don't actually hit the brakes until *starting* the turn, which just makes them more likely to slip.

Answer (score 1):

It's a poorly written question, but in the end you are told that:

- The cyclist goes in a circular track (centripetal acceleration);
- His speed decreases at a constant rate (tangential acceleration).

Your equation for the speed of the cyclist is fine, however it does not help you at all. For it to be useful, you'd need to either be given a time/distance at which the net acceleration should be calculated. But, you're not given that info. Therefore, you are left to assume that you want the acceleration at the start of the track.

Your doubts however are reasonable. The question should have specified you want the acceleration as the cyclist enters the turn.

Comment: Yeah, I should have thought about that, I don't know why I didn't realize that there is a lack of information. Are most high school textbooks like this? or is mine just really bad (this isn't is the only badly framed question)?

Comment: My high school textbook was decent, but this will change from school to school.  You could bring this issue up with your teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, **make sure** you convert all data to S.I. units ($\mathrm{ms^{-1}}$ and $\mathrm{m}$), as incorrect results will be obtained otherwise.

The velocity going into the turn is:

$$v(t)=v_0-a_t t$$
where:
$$v_0=v(0)$$
So the centripetal acceleration as a function of time is:
$$a_c(t)=\frac{v(t)^2}{r}$$
and the net acceleration is the vector sum of $a_c$ and $a_t$ (the latter is constant):
$$\boxed{a_{net}(t)=\sqrt{a_c(t)^2+a_t^2}}$$